# Text mining- how to build a term-document matrix

Tags: r, tm

What I am trying to do is to load a csv file, and convert to an term-document matrix.

Here is part of my code:

```
myCorpus<-read.csv('alert-sample-data-4-mining.csv', head=TRUE)
TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control=list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf)))
```

But get an error message said:  **Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "data.frame"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things here -- you're not loading the tm library and you're not creating a corpus. Try something like this (assuming your text data is in a field called "text" in the csv file):

```
library(tm)
myCorpus <- read.csv("alert-sample-data-4-mining.csv")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(myCorpus$text))
TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
```

Comment: could you explain "assuming your text data is in a field called "text" in the csv file", thanks

Comment: You have some data in a csv file. The first row of the data is the names of the column headings, and all subsequent rows are data. Some column contains text that you want to use to build a term document matrix. I'm assuming the column heading for this (aka the value in the first row of the csv file for this column) is called "text".

Comment: Use `str(myCorpus)` and see what the text column header is named.  josilber said he assumed it was text for explanation's sake, though it likely is not.

Comment: @josilber I have a csv file, whose head is: DATE Alert and OriginatingAddress.
How should I build a term-document matrix based on two columns: DATE and Alert.
The row will have the alert and the column will have the day. The entry indicates the number of occurrences of the alert in a day.

Comment: Are you trying to determine the number of times a particular alert appeared on each day?